How to use Skeleton in PrimeNG DataTable when retrieving data from a Rest API?
I am trying to display Skeleton in a PrimeNG DataTable while retrieving information from a REST API.
When the information is received Skeleton should hide and display the data.
There is a example: https://primeng.org/skeleton#datatable
But this example does not show how to substitute the Skeleton for the data received.

The example doesn't show how to replace it because it is just an example. What I suggest is adding a boolean initialized as true, and change it to false when the subscription ends. You can try this:
export class Foo implements OnInit {
  isLoading: boolean = true;

  constructor(private fooService: FooService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fooService.getBar().subscribe(data => {
      ...your code
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}

And the HTML (following the primeng example) would be this:
<p-table [value]="products" [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem' }">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
    <tr>
      <td *ngIf="!isLoading; else loading">{{ product.code }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="!isLoading; else loading">{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="!isLoading; else loading">{{ product.category }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="!isLoading; else loading">{{ product.quantity }}</td>
      <ng-template #loading>
        <td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td>
        <td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td>
        <td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td>
        <td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td>
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>

Make sure to change the code as you need, this is just an example

To show a Skeleton in a PrimeNG DataTable while fetching data from a REST API:

set up your component and service;
create a boolean 'loading' variable initialized to true;
define skeleton and table columns using pTemplate
conditionally render the Skeleton or data table with *ngIf based on 'loading'
and set 'loading' to false once data is retrieved.

api.service.ts

app.component.html

app.component.ts

